# Web scraping in Chrome Console- iterate over rows in mat-tab element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

DISCLAIMER: I do not know JS,  it is an assignment for my work.

I have been asked to withdraw scrape some data from a Google Marketing page using Chrome Console.

The HTML code I need to scrape looks like this:

[The code in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOJaj.jpg)

I made the following code where I created a dictionary and then used `document.Selector()`to take the data but I only take it from one row.

```
var IntegrationDetails = [{}]

IntegrationDetails[0]["Property Name"] = document.querySelector("JSPath").innerText

IntegrationDetails[0]["Advertiser"] = document.querySelector("JSPath").innerText

IntegrationDetails[0]["Tracking ID"] = document.querySelector("JSPath").innerText

IntegrationDetails[0]["Account"] = document.querySelector("JSPath").innerText

IntegrationDetails[0]["Organisation name"] = document.querySelector("JSPath").innerText

IntegrationDetails[0]["Integrations with reporting data"] = document.querySelector("JSPath").innerText

IntegrationDetails[0]["Integrations with Cost Data"] = document.querySelector("JSPath").innerText

IntegrationDetails[0]["Integrations with Remarketing Lists"] = document.querySelector("JSPath").innerText

copy(IntegrationDetails)
```

I do not know how to iterate over every row in the mat-tab element and append each row to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found it worked is the one below.
I also needed to increment the [i] based on the length of the table in order to not overwrite the data.

```
var IntegrationDetails = []

for(let i=0;i < document.querySelectorAll('mat-row').length; i++) {
    IntegrationDetails.push( {
        "Property Name":  document.querySelectorAll('mat-row')[i].querySelectorAll("mat-cell")[1].innerText,
        "Advertiser": document.querySelectorAll('mat-row')[i].querySelectorAll("mat-cell")[2].innerText,
        "Tracking ID" : document.querySelectorAll('mat-row')[i].querySelectorAll("mat-cell")[3].innerText,
        "Account" : document.querySelectorAll('mat-row')[i].querySelectorAll("mat-cell")[4].innerText,
        "Organisation name" : document.querySelectorAll('mat-row')[i].querySelectorAll("mat-cell")[5].innerText,
        "Int with report data" : document.querySelectorAll('mat-row')[i].querySelectorAll("mat-cell")[6].innerText,
        "Int with Cost Data" : document.querySelectorAll('mat-row')[i].querySelectorAll("mat-cell")[7].innerText,
        "Int with Remarketing Lists" : document.querySelectorAll('mat-row')[i].querySelectorAll("mat-cell")[8].innerText
    })
}

copy(IntegrationDetails)
```